# What if an interviewer asks that I must bring some relevant work with me?

Tags: interviewing

The interview is about either web-developing and/or mobile coding.
I've been asked to bring some work with me, either web pages or anything related to the job offered.

I do not really want to show them anything in code, that's mine and I am just applying for job, not showcasing my work.

- Can I just show them demos and such i.e. web pages and/or executables.
- What if they ask for code i.e. PHP or C++ or whatever?

I have most of my work on internet but what if they ask for more? It is suspicious or it could might help me getting the job?

A friend of mine said that I should never show my work, just my expertise in positions but I have never had official jobs in software development... I was always a freelancer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I do not really want to show them anything in code

That is what they're interested in and asked for, so expect to waste your time if you don't take some. I would be interested in both the site and the code behind it, not so much for it's sake as code, but how well it's structured, secured, maintainable etc,.

Comment: I see, thanx. So i should be willing showing / explaining my work, like showing them how i am usually dealing with this stuff.

Comment: Yes, you should build something just to showcase your abilities if you don't want them looking at paid work you own. In fact demos like that tend to be tidier than the real thing which may have been modified and patched several times. Live sites can be pretty messy after a while.

Answer (score 1):

> I am just applying for job, not showcasing my work.

But showcasing your work is an important way of getting a job. For some jobs, it's expected to have a portfolio (models, photographers, etc). For programmers, this is becoming more and more common.

Of course, it may be that all your work was done while being employed, and you do not have the right to show that code. But then, just say so. But many programmers have some personal project, or open source contributions. A [github](http://github.com) account can make it easy to build a portfolio.

> I do not really want to show them anything in code, that's mine

I really wonder about this attitude. If you feel strongly that code you have written is yours, do you really want to work for someone else?

Comment: Oh, but perhaps all the code he's written is *really* his own.